# CollectionView is not showing any item

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I have a viewController with a collectionView.

I have set the collectionView delegates as follows, in viewController and also at storyboard:

```
modelosCV.delegate = self
modelosCV.dataSource = self
```

I have created all collectionView methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filtrados ? modelosFiltrados.count : modelos.count
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



    let cellModelos = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "modelo", for: indexPath) as! ModelosCollectionViewCell



    print(filtrados ? modelosFiltrados[indexPath.row].icono : modelos[indexPath.row].icono)

    let foto_modelo = filtrados ? modelosFiltrados[indexPath.row].icono : modelos[indexPath.row].icono

    let modelo_nombre = filtrados ? modelosFiltrados[indexPath.row].nombre : modelos[indexPath.row].nombre
    cellModelos.modelo_nombre.text = modelo_nombre

    let url = URL(string: "https://j../iconos/"+foto_modelo)

    UIImage.loadFrom(url: url!) { image in
        cellModelos.modelo_icono.image = image

    }


    return cellModelos


}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


       let padding: CGFloat =  50
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding

        return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: 242)
    }
```

I am populating the collectionView from a remote JSON source:

```
func downloadJSONModelos(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {

    var categoria = ""



    let cat = self.defaults.string(forKey: "nueva_alarma_categoria")
    if (cat == "Móviles"){
        categoria = "3"
    }
    if (cat == "Tablets"){
        categoria = "5"
    }
    if (cat == "Smartwatches"){
        categoria = "7"
    }
    let marca_id = self.defaults.string(forKey: "nueva_alarma_marca_id")
    let url = URL(string: "https:.....php?marca="+marca_id!+"&cat="+categoria)


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,response,error) in

        print(data as Any)
        print(response as Any)

        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.modelos = try JSONDecoder().decode([Modelos].self, from: data!)


                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }

            }catch{

            }
            print(self.modelos)
        }
    }.resume()


}
```

The app is receiving the JSON array as it is printed in the output, but the collectionView remains empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: does your `cellForItemAt` return valid cell ? or nil .. check it first

Comment: also check `numberOfItemsInSection` is called by your controller or not ?

Comment: and after getting data ... are you calling reload data ?

Comment: @jawadAli, yes to all your questions

Comment: can you send the code via wetransfer ?

Comment: @jawadAli, sorry for the late answer

Comment: @jawadAli, what do you need?

Comment: you ca send me code ... i will check the issue ... you can transfer via wetransfer.com

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `viewDidLoad` :

```
yourCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "yourXibName", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "modelo")
```

And reload your `collectionView` with `yourCollectionView.reloadData()` at where you append element to your array from `JSON`.

Hope it helps...

Comment: in the same project I have other viewControllers with collectionViews, all of them populated from remote JSONs, and all are working but this one. Up to now there were no need to include the code from your proposal, but I will try anyway.

Comment: So, just try register cell.

Comment: Cell should be already registered at storyBoard using the identier, isn't it?

Comment: But I am not using any nibname, what should I put there?

Comment: @mvasco did you create a custom cell?

Comment: I had to remove all code and start again, now it seems to work.

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with registering cells,  but thank you